# clean permalink removing-php extensions from url

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i would like clean urls so when a visitor is served http://localhost/MYEVENTS/filename/ instead of http://localhost/MYEVENTS/filename.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /MYEVENTS/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /MYEVENTS/index.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: How about http://localhost/MYEVENTS/filename/25/ goes to http://localhost/MYEVENTS/filename.php?event_id=25?